# Prove that the set $X = \{x \in R^L_+| u(x) \geq \bar u\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that the set $X = \{x \in R^L_+| u(x) \geq \bar u\}$, with $\bar{u}$ a positive number and $R^L_+$ is the space of vectors in $R^L$ such that their elements are non-negative, is closed.

Saw this statement in the textbook but I'm not sure how this is the case when we don't have any restrictions on $u(x)$ such as continuity. I can prove this if it is continuous, but I'm not sure how to do it if  isn't.

EDIT: The textbook most likely left out continuity condition on $u(x)$

Comment: You might want to expand on your notation a bit. What's $\bar u$? What's $R^L_+$?

Comment: $\bar{u}$ is a positive constant and $R^L_+$ is the set of vectors in $R^L$ such that their elements are nonnegative.

Comment: So $\bar u$ is just an arbitrary positive number? And $L$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be false for arbitrary functions. Indeed, let $A\subset R^L_+$ be any set, $u$ the characteristic function of $A$ and $\bar u=1$. Then $\{x\in R^L_+: u(x)\ge \bar u\}=A$, which need not be open.

Comment: Would the result change if $u(x)$ is monotonic, meaning $u(x) > u(y)$ for all $x >= y$? Here $x >= y$ is a comparison element-wise, so every element of $x$ is at least as great as $y$.

Comment: What do you mean by at least as great as $y$? $y$ is a vector. Also, I'd conjecture that the author of the problem probably left out the word "continuity" from the statement.

Comment: I meant component wise, so $x_1 \geq y_1, x_2 \geq y_2$ and so forth. But I do agree that the lack of continuity restriction on $u()$ is strange.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a harder question. I don't quite see the answer right now. I'll update if I think of anything. Constructing discontinuous functions that are monotonic in that ordering seems a bit unpleasant.